# Setting Hotmail to cache fewer old messages

Tags: outlook.com, cache

Whenever I have a tab open with Hotmail running in Chrome, it takes up a large chunk of memory (around 250 M).  I've had the account for a long time, so I have a ton of email messages stored in it.  I'm assuming the Hotmail interface is caching a significant number of messages to allow for fast opening, though I've never found any evidence to back this up.

Is there a setting in Hotmail to prevent it from caching so many messages all at once?

Comment: Have you tried disabling extensions and seeing if it is a problem? In particular Adblock and Facetime have reportedly caused problems - http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/chrome/ribl1h8iSoM/discussion

Comment: @JohnC Hotmail still works, though.  It just eats memory.  I have AdBlock, but it doesn't seem to be affecting the amount of memory being used by that tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an absolute lark, I tried out their new Outlook.com (from the "Options" menu), and the memory usage seems to have dropped from 250M down to 143M.

I'm not sure if the newer site uses a different framework or if they *are* doing something differently with the message caching, but this seems like a good solution for the time being.